# How to create pretty face filter like snapchat in Core Image iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I am trying to build image filters in iOS and was wondering how I can achieve the same effect as snapchat "pretty face" filter with Core Image? Has anyone done that? Doesn't have to be exactly the same, but at least similar...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I google "snapchat pretty face filter" I don't find anything, so I'm not sure what filter you're referring to. Please provide some sort of example, this isn't a very constructive post at the moment.

Comment: You can use the Unity and OpenCV in the same time or you can use the openGL of course. We have developed clone filter like snapchat. please check my experiences. and then this tech is private by looksery. onefire. Thanks. Here is the link of the app that I have develop. https://www.dropbox.com/s/47xib6wcvo1l4xe/Facefilter.apk?dl=0

Comment: did you figure out how to do that ?